# TypeError: descriptor 'readlines' of 'file' object needs argument

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a Tkinter Login Gui but if I click Log in it the displays the message "TypeError: descriptor 'readlines' of 'file' object needs argument" I tried looking for an answer and most of them were because of case-sensitive errors. Could someone please help me out. I've set up the profile.txt file properly(I'm 100% sure)

```
def LogIn():
    name=input("Please enter your name: ")
    file = open(name.lower() + "profile.txt", "r")
import Tkinter
import time
window = Tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Python Games Login")
window.geometry("270x210")
window.configure(bg="#39d972")

def callback():
    line = file.readlines()
    username = user.get()
    password = passw.get()
    if username == line[1] and password == line[2]:
            message.configure(text = "Logged in.")
    else:
        message.configure(text = "Username and password don't match the      account \n under the name;\n \'" + name + "\'. \nPlease try again.")

title1 = Tkinter.Label(window, text="--Log in to play the Python Games--  \n",   bg="#39d972")
usertitle = Tkinter.Label(window, text="---Username---", bg="#39d972")
passtitle = Tkinter.Label(window, text="---Password---", bg="#39d972")
message = Tkinter.Label(window, bg="#39d972")
user = Tkinter.Entry(window)
passw = Tkinter.Entry(window, show='*')
go = Tkinter.Button(window, text="Log in!", command = callback, bg="#93ff00")
title1.pack()
usertitle.pack()
user.pack()
passtitle.pack()
passw.pack()
go.pack()
message.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: One of the few reasons why you should not name your variables after [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). Don't name your file variable as `file` as it is a builtin

Comment: Put `print( type(file) )` right before the place where you call readlines().  The type is not what you expect it is ...

Comment: seconding @BhargavRao's comment

Comment: I tried changing the variable name but then it asks me to define it. I wasn't too sure what to do so i tried "print( type(file) )" before i call readline(). with the original text but that made no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are assigning to `file` in function and it's not propagated to the globals thus in function `callback` it's not what you are expecting.

`file` it's (as hinted in comments) builtin python type therefore you receive this kind of error and not `NameError` as it would be for undefined variable.

Please check for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) to get better understanding how variable scopes work in python.